# How to set configuration sendmail in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, sendmail

i just install sendmail on my server nginx.
and i have project nodejs.
so, i used smtp configuration for sending mail. But email still cannot send.

so i used sendmail. But anyone know how to set configuration for sendmail?
This is my configuration before:
'use strict'

```
const Env = use('Env')

module.exports = {
  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Connection
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Connection to be used for sending emails. Each connection needs to
  | define a driver too.
  |
  */
  connection: Env.get('MAIL_CONNECTION', 'smtp'),

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | SMTP
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here we define configuration for sending emails via SMTP.
  |
  */
  smtp: {
    driver: 'smtp',
    pool: true,
    port: 2525,
    host: Env.get('MAIL_HOST'),
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: Env.get('MAIL_USERNAME'),
      pass: Env.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
    },
    maxConnections: 5,
    maxMessages: 100,
    rateLimit: 10
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple points of possible failures in your configuration and not enough data in your question. You may try to search for problems in the following order:

1. Make sure that sendmail is configured to listen for connections at specified port. Port number 2525 is rather unusual, default ports for sendmail are 25 and 587.
2. Check with telnet or similar program that you can connect to sendmail port, it is not blocked with a firewall and sendmail sends you HELO/EHLO greeting on connect.
3. Make sure that MAIL_HOST and other environment variables are set to correct values and are visible to your script.
4. Use some local mail client to send email via sendmail with MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD credentials. Check sendmail log for possible errors if email was not delivered. Make sure that authorization in sendmail is configured correctly.
5. Try to send email from your script and check sendmail log for errors.

You may want to ask some help for steps 1, 4 and 5 at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com)